# get image contain not download again

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, yii

Iam using yii framework. i have created a function/controller which check the image file is exist in the directory, if file is exists using file_get_contents() function pass the image and set the background of the div tag. If file is not exists the default image file contain is passing.

syntax php:-

```
  header('Content-Type: image/png');
  echo file_get_contents($location);
```

And in javascript i create a function to draw adiv and set background of that div 
Syntax:-

```
 function drawDiv()
{
$('.divID').html("<div id="test"></div>")
$('#test').css({background-image : url('http://location/test/getimage')});
}
```

when ever i redraw the div again the image is download every time.
if i set the url absolute path  it download once.

what i want is that if the image is exist or not exist the should download once.
plz solve issue..
if you have another solution tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [**clone**](http://api.jquery.com/clone/). From a quick test, the image isn't redownloaded. (See screengrab at the bottom, or open your network panel and test)

#### Implementation

So, you could have `#test` set up (with the background image, and styling you want), but hidden. And just `clone()` it whenever you want.

```
<div id="test" style="background-image:url(http://location/test/getimage);display:none;">
</div>
```

And your Javascript would be

```
$("#test").clone().show().prependTo("body");
```

#### [Try the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7xtnz6s/)

- Notice the image is only downloaded once (open your network panel, and see)

#### Code test

```js
$( "img" ).clone().prependTo( "body" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.google.co.uk//images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want to clone the image. redraw the same div.

Comment: Redrawing the same div is....cloning? You can do `$("#test").clone().show().prependTo("body");` - check the updated answer

Comment: thank you for reply. but my issue is div height width and background-image come from the server side by this value i am redrawing the div. when ever i redraw that div the background image get downloading and background image value come from the server side. so i don't want to re-download same image..